# Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: benchmark.deeplearn.online

Tags: java, deep-learning

I'm working a deep learning application and when I try to run it, the following exception is thrown: 
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: benchmark.deeplearn.online
How I can solve this?

Comment: `CodeNotFoundError`

Comment: Are you getting this Exception while running DeepLearning4j? Look at this issue https://github.com/SkymindIO/SKIL-CE/issues/34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is saying your code tried to make a connection over the internet to benchmark.deeplearn.online but failed.  Go to the machine your code is running on (if its not your local machine) and from that machine, run "ping benchmark.deeplearn.online" from the command line.  See if that machine can connect.  If it can't, then the problem is with networking and not with your code.

Comment: The ping results is this: The ping request could not find the benchmark.deeplearn.online host. Check the name and try again. So, the problem is with the networking, ok? Any suggestion for this?

Comment: Yeah like @Lothar said, I also can't get to that location.  Are you certain benchmark.deeplearn.online exists?  I don't think that's an actual website anything can connect to.

Answer (score 0):

An `UnknownHostException` can mean different things:

- You did something wrong in your application that lead to the inability to resolve the hostname.
- Your operating system can't resolve the hostname to an IP, e.g. because it's not configured correctly so it can't ask the name servers out there for the IP
- The hostname you provided is wrong.

The first possibility can be ruled out by opening a shell and e.g. do a `ping [hostname]` as SpareTheRod already told you to try. If you receive an error that the hostname can't be resolved, you can rule out anything concerning your application.

The second possibility can be ruled out (making possibility three the most likely reason) is to check the hostname on another machine or simply google for it. I tried it here on my computer and I can't resolve this hostname, either, so we can rule out your systems configuration.

So most likely the hostname you're trying to access simply doesn't exist with that name.